# What is Best File Reader in between BufferInputReader Vs LineNumberReader vs Stream in Java in terms of Memory, Processor, Time

Tags: java, stream, filereader, bufferedinputstream

I tried all three reading process but cant judge which is best in term of

**Memory Utilization, Processor Usage, Time complexity**

I have seen many solutions online but no one has come up with perfect conclusion on above terms.

I have tried few thing please check the code and let me know how to make it more optimize in above highlighted requirement.

Below is my Code.

**NOTE: Out.txt is 3Gb text file**

```
package Reader;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.LineNumberReader;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.stream.Stream;

/*
 *  Comparing Execution time of BufferInputReader Vs LineNumberReader Vs 
Stream
 *  o/p > Effeciency of BufferInputReader to LineNumberReader is around :: 
200%

 *  
 */
public class LineReaderBufferInputStream {

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    //LineReaderBufferInputStream
    LineReaderBufferInputStream lr = new LineReaderBufferInputStream();
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();

    int count = lr.countLinesUsingLineNumberReader("D://out.txt");

    long endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long c1 = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(count + " LineReaderBufferInputStream Time taken:: " + c1);

    startTime = System.nanoTime();

    count = countLinesByBufferIpStream("D://out.txt");

    endTime = System.nanoTime();
    long c2 = (endTime - startTime);
    System.out.println(count + " BufferedInputStream Time taken:: " + c2);

    System.out.println("Effeciency of BufferInputReader to LineNumberReader is around :: " + (c1) / c2 * 100 + "%");

    // Java8 line by line reader
    //read file into stream, try-with-resources
    startTime = System.nanoTime();
    long cn = countLinesUsingStream("D://out.txt");
    endTime = System.nanoTime();

    System.out.println(cn +" Using Stream :: " + (endTime - startTime));

}

public int countLinesUsingLineNumberReader(String filename) throws IOException {
    LineNumberReader reader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(filename));
    int cnt = 0;
    String lineRead = "";
    while ((lineRead = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        //if you need to do anything with lineReader.
    }

    cnt = reader.getLineNumber();
    reader.close();
    return cnt;
}

public static int countLinesByBufferIpStream(String filename) throws IOException {
    InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(filename));
    try {
        byte[] c = new byte[1024];
        int count = 1;
        int readChars = 0;
        boolean empty = true;
        while ((readChars = is.read(c)) != -1) {
            empty = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readChars; ++i) {
                if (c[i] == '\n') {
                    ++count;
                }
            }
        }
        return (count == 0 && !empty) ? 1 : count;
    } finally {
        is.close();
    }
}

public static long countLinesUsingStream(String fileName) throws IOException{
    try (Stream<String> streamReader = Files.lines(Paths.get("D://out.txt"))) {

        return streamReader.count();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

}

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to know which one of them i should use to read a very large and which one of them is more effective.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One remark: it is good to explicitly pass the encoding of a portable file, as the default encoding may vary.

The older default encoding for binary file data to Unicode String was the platform encoding.

The newer `Files.lines` will use UTF-8 by default (hurray).

This means that UTF-8 is a bit more slow conversion, and error prone on wrong non-ASCII chars, as UTF-8 multibyte sequences require a correct bit format.

1. In general `Files.lines` and others like `Files.newBufferedReader` are sufficiently fast.
2. For huge files one might use a ByteBuffer/CharBuffer, a memory mapped file via a FileChannel. Simply search on the net. The gain is not that large.

Not converting, using a (Buffered)InputStream / ByteBuffer, is faster than conversion to text.

Java stores (Unicode) text in a String as array of `char` which is 2-byte. The newest java can store it alternatively also in single byte encoding (a jvm option), which might save memory.

Possibly better might be to have the text compressed, as `Out.txt.gz` for instance. Trading CPU against disk speed.

Answer (score 1):

If you are asking which of those classes is fastest or uses least memory *in general*, then there is no answer.  It depends critically on the task you are performing.  And how you *use* the classes.

If you are asking for the fastest way to *just* count the lines in a file, then the fastest way will be to use `InputStream` to read directly into a `ByteBuffer`, then count the line terminators.  This will also use the least memory.

Here's why:

- Anything that generates a `String` for each line read is going to do a lot of unnecessary copying, and generate a lot of garbage.
- Anything that uses a `Reader` is going to do a decode byte data to character data.  This includes `LineNumberReader`
- If use `BufferedInputStream` and read into a large `byte[]`, you are effectively doing your own (simple) buffering.  You may as well use the `InputStream` directly.
- If you use `read(byte[])` you are doing an extra copy of the data into your `byte[]`.

There are a number of tutorials that can help you to understand how to use `ByteBuffer` for fast I/O.  For example:

- The ["Java NIO Buffer"](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-nio/buffers.html) tutorial page in the Jenkov.com Java tutorials.

---

However ...

In real world applications involving really large files, the performance bottleneck frequently turns out to be the performance of the file system and storage devices, or what you do with the data to process it ... once you have it in memory.

It is *advisable* to avoid optimizing your application's I/O until you have the higher level functionality working, and are in a position to write and run a benchmark.  Then you should profile the application to find where the bottlenecks really are.  Finally, optimizing the bottlenecks.

Unless you are really experienced (and often even if you are) your instincts about where best to spend optimization effort are often incorrect.

---

Finally, the fastest way to count the lines in a file is probably to forget about Java and use a standard native code utility; e.g. on Unix / Linux / MacOS use `wc pathname`.

Comment: Hi @stephen, what you think of stream in case of shared file system

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "shared" file system.  All file systems are shared!   But the distinction is probably not relevant to how you should read files.

Comment: Using multiple threads to read a single file is a bad idea.  Complex, and the performance benefit is doubtful due to various things in the file system / OS layers.  Either way, it probably makes no difference to my answer.  (Except for complexity.  For example, I don't see how you could implement to get multi-threading benefit via the `Stream::count()` approach.)